# Cannot build Storm for the storm-starter example

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, distributed-computing, building

I am a complete newbie with Apache storm. I tried to follow the storm-starter. I cloned the repository, and then I tried to build and install locally storm. Unfortunately I cannot even do that. The storm-metrics jar cannot  be built

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building storm-metrics 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ storm-metrics ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/apple/storm/external/storm-metrics/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (cleanup) @ storm-metrics ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (prepare) @ storm-metrics ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Downloading sigar native binaries...
      [get] Getting: https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
      [get] To: /var/root/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/sigar/1.6.4/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
      [get] Can't get https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip to /var/root/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/sigar/1.6.4/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] storm-metrics ...................................... FAILURE [  2.818 s]
[INFO] storm-cassandra .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-mqtt-parent .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-mqtt ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-mqtt-examples ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-mongodb ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-clojure ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-starter ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-kafka-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-opentsdb ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-kafka-monitor ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-kinesis ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-druid ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-submit-tools ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.867 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-31T11:52:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/270M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (prepare) on project storm-metrics: An Ant BuildException has occured: Can't get https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip to /var/root/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/sigar/1.6.4/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I tried to follow the link : https://magelan.googlecode.com/files/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip but indeed there is nothing on this page.

So I have been stuck on this for like 4 hours, I cannot even run a topology yet... Please help :(

Comment: By the way I am working on a macbook pro 2012 with el capitan OS. to build I ran the following command "sudo mvn clean install -DskipTests=true" in the folder "Storm" created when I cloned the rpository

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the download link for hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip has changed to

https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/magelan/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip

Try to do the following:

In the file `external/storm-metrics/pom.xml` set the entry for `<sigar.download.url>` to `<sigar.download.url>https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/magelan/hyperic-sigar-${sigar.version}.zip</sigar.download.url>` and then re-run `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`

In my case I grepped for all occurrences of the old download link and replaced them with the new link, but I guess this should not be necessary as all the other places where the link occurred were generated in the build process. Replacing the link worked for me. It is also weird, that the link already is corrected in their GitHub repository, but is not, when you download it as a zip file from GitHub.

Comment: I just now see, that they actually answered your issue post. I guess this makes my answer obsolete then...

Answer (score 0):

Below existing issue link :

https://github.com/apache/storm/commit/ef3c4de133528d04f76a43a0e87e72cea19e173e

I tried to build with latest storm-starter clone and it's working fine. Update your repository and try again. Should work fine.